# how to disable Haproxy ip route modifications

Tags: ip, haproxy, iproute

I installed haproxy to my server and on internet I saw that I need to run these commands:

```
/sbin/ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
/sbin/ip route add local 0.0.0.0./0 dev lo table 100
```

Now I would like to remove the haproxy but after I removed it I can't access the specific port of my server where haproxy was load balancing.

I installed haproxy again and is working. How can I remove these changes in order to also remove haproxy and to work?

Answer (score 0):

For the rules:

```
ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table 100
```

For the routes:

```
ip route flush <inet prefix>
```

That should work for you because I used the same thing to do the same thing (removing haproxy's custom routes and rules).